# D3.js with Turf.js error: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Each LinearRing of a Polygon must have 4 or more Positions."

Tags: d3.js, topojson, turfjs

I'm trying to loop through a series of polygons to see if my single point exists in one of those polygons. From what I've read I need to import the topojson, convert it to a geojson object, and loop through each polygon checking the point. Here's what I have using D3, Topojson and Turf...

```
const point = turf.point([long, lat]);
d3.json('data/myAreas.json').then((myAreas) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(myAreas.objects);
    const geo = topojson.feature(myAreas, myAreas.objects[keys[0]]);
    geo.features.forEach((area) => {
      const searchWithin = turf.polygon([[area.geometry.coordinates[0]]]);
      const ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(point, searchWithin);
      console.log('ptsWithin?', ptsWithin);
    });
});
```

When it gets to `const searchWithin = turf.polygon([[area.geometry.coordinates[0]]]);` it throws the following error...

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Each LinearRing of a Polygon must have 4 or more Positions.
```

I've tried D3's `d3.geoContain()` but it threw `false` every time. I'm open to alternative solutions that will check to see if a lat/lng coordinate is within a topojson shape. Thanks.

Comment: you aren't using `searchWithin`. Do you really need the double `[]` for `turf.polygon` maybe `searchWithin = turf.polygon(area.geometry.coordinates);`

Comment: Sorry, 3am post lol. I've edited my original post. Error persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is what ended up working for me, replacing `turf.polygon()` with `turf.multiPolygon`

```
const point = turf.point([long, lat]);
d3.json('data/myAreas.json').then((areas) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(areas.objects);
  const geo = topojson.feature(areas, areas.objects[keys[0]]);
  geo.features.forEach((k, i) => {
    const searchWithin = turf.multiPolygon([[k.geometry.coordinates[0]]]);
    const ptsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(point, searchWithin);
    if (ptsWithin.features.length > 0) {
      console.log('ptsWithin?', i, ptsWithin); // The index of the containing polygon
      console.log(geo.features[i]); // The features for the corresponding polygon
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It "worked" (didn't get the error), but the resulting polygon was incorrect in my case. [mwarren's answer did the trick for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57149860/1064325)

Comment: Well for me it worked with turf.polygon only while working into react native. But definitely, this helped me to understand the problem and was able to fix it... thank you @layne

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error.

I later discovered that I hadn't sufficiently nested the array I was presenting to turf.polygon().

Taking the following line from your example above

```
const searchWithin = turf.polygon([[area.geometry.coordinates[0]]]);
```

I think this should actually be (notice extra [] brackets):

```
const searchWithin = turf.polygon([[[area.geometry.coordinates[0]]]]);
```

Here's an example from the turfjs site:

```
var poly = turf.polygon([[[0,29],[3.5,29],[2.5,32],[0,29]]]);
```